# How do you update a client's iOS app without getting access to their developer account?

Tags: ios, app-store

A while back we built a Unity iOS app for a client and transferred the ownership of the app to the client's Apple developer account.

We now need to push an update to the app.

I understand that if we had access to their developer account, we can do it?
i.e.

- download the certificate & the provisioning profile to the build
  machine
- bump up the bundle version and build number
- build the Unity app
- open the project/workspace in Xcode
- load the correct provisioning profile
- archive
- sign & upload
- create a new release on app store connect?

But the client is hesitant to give us access to their developer account.

So, **without getting access to their developer account,** how can we build the app and give them the binaries so that they can upload and release it as an update? Appreciate it if you can include the steps for both us as the developer and the client.

TIA.

Comment: You can't.  It is their app.  They need to add you as a team member or you need to provide them with source code they can build.  They can add you to their team and limit your access to only the one app.

Comment: Can we build the app on their behalf (using their certificate and provisioning profile) and give them the binaries (whichever format that is) so that they can upload it themselves?

Comment: Yes. They will need to provide you with the signing certificate and then you can provide the ipa for them to upload

Comment: OK, so that's an option then.
But the steps aren't clear to me. Assuming we have received the certificate and the provisioning profile, do I archive, then distribute app ->  as Development? How does the client upload to the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need provisioning profiles and certificates to build and export the app and share with your client to upload it to AppStore.

- Archive the App
- Distribute App > App Store Connect > Export
  [image] [image]
- Share the exported ipa file with your client.

Comment: Thank you. This is great. 

But how do they then upload it to the app store connect?

Comment: They will need to use the app transporter from Apple.

Comment: There is tool provided by Apple called Transporter (use this tool to upload ipa) https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10152019a